# Boosting 3.0 - 4.6 Volts to 5V

Tags: diodes, integrated-circuit, boost, schottky, buck-boost

I found this circuit that will auto switch between power between USB (5V) or a LiPo Battery (3.0V - 4.2V range).

[image]

The schottky diode, D4, can have a voltage drop of about 0.4V which is too high for me. I need the **voltage to be 5V with 0.2V tolerance at the maximum**. I'm thinking of using an IC similar to U2 in the schematic. But rather than a 3.3V output step-down IC, I'll need a 5V boost output one and at least a 600mA output.

Is there an IC that can do that even with a 4.6V input?

Comment: This may be doable with a boost or buckboost regulator; unfortunately it won't be a drop-in replacement and answers that simply suggest an off-the-shelf part are discouraged since they may become outdated.

Comment: @nanofarad if the part is available from places like Digikey, it'd still be very helpful.

Comment: A quick [search](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1098=323652&sf=0&FV=1779%7C249171%2C-8%7C739&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25) showed [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/TPS63002DRCR/296-19644-1-ND/1016513) as a possibility among a number of other options. It requires a PCB layout with an inductor, some capacitors, and a resistor around it.

Comment: Side note, I think Q3 is upside down. Right now, Q3 isn't acting as a switch and current from Vbat is flowing through the body diode.

Comment: @nanofarad Thanks! I'll take a look

Comment: @Jay I thought so too that it's upside down but a lot of other examples had it in the same in that orientation. Apparently this will allow VBAT to be fully on when there is no VBUS. Here is one example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501139/how-to-automatically-disconnect-from-battery-when-usb-5v-is-present/501162#501162