# Switching between VCC and V_BAT

Tags: diodes, battery-charging, coin-cell

I am designing a circuit for a GPS receiver IC and RTC.

As both of them require a V_BCKP connection I will be using a CR2032 (non-rechargeable) battery for V_BAT supply.
To make sure the minimum use of battery I want to mainly use VCC (3.3V) from my MCU whenever it is powered on and use the battery only when the MCU is off.

[image: Schematic]

Although this is the same circuit as recommended in the Datasheet for a "rechargeable battery", I don't understand why this won't work for a non-rechargeable battery. Please help me understand.

My proposal to the circuit is using 2 diodes and 3.3 VCC will be automatically selected because it has higher potential than the battery I am using.

[image]

Comment: Because the 3.3 volt power will be illegally forcing charge into the non-rechargeable battery.

Comment: okay, So how do I avoid this and use V_BAT only when 3.3V is off ?

Comment: This is a Q and A site and not a talking shop or forum. Do some investigations and post a circuit proposal to your question.

Comment: This may answer your question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501139/how-to-automatically-disconnect-from-battery-when-usb-5v-is-present/501162#501162

Comment: I have posted a proposal. Please check

Comment: Yes, you second circuit will work as intended. Isolating the supply and battery from each other.

Comment: You should probably use schottky diodes for least volt drop when conducting.

Comment: Do I need to add any additional pull up or pull down ?

Comment: and do I still need to keep the 390R?

Comment: Like mentioned above, it's better to use a Schottky diode to keep the voltage drop low (about 0.3V).   But you can get down to almost no voltage drop with a few more components.    Here's something to get you started    $$$$ https://www.insidegadgets.com/2011/06/07/change-voltage-sources-automatically-by-using-a-mosfet/

Comment: It should be made extremely sure not to accidentally exceed the safe limit for accidentally charging the battery. A schottky diode has larger reverse leakage than a standard diode. To fulfill UL requirements, and allow for one diode to break, sometimes two standard diodes are needed to make sure reverse charging current is below 1uA.

Comment: I was suggested this part as it has 3 diodes in it. Looks like this will work for me. https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/196/Infineon-BAT54SERIES-DS-v01_01-en-1225947.pdf

Comment: 2* diodes in it